# Accessing values from embedded slice in struct

Tags: go, slice

I am trying to access values from an embedded slice in a struct. How can I do so via indexing, and without calling the private embedded object explicitly (which is not even an option when accessing from outside the package), if that's possible at all?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type A struct {
    aSlice
}

type aSlice []string

func main() {
    a := A{[]string{"hello", "world"}}
    fmt.Println(a.aSlice[0]) // works, but can't be accessed outside package
    fmt.Println(a[0]) // doesn't work, but looking for this something like this
}
```

Comment: Also related: [Go: Embedding a primitive type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38811253/go-embedding-a-primitive-type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the answer in this post: [golang anonymous field of type map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26447066/golang-anonymous-field-of-type-map)

> Only fields and methods may be "promoted" when you embed. For
>   everything else they act as just another field.

In this case the struct would be the equivalent of:

```
type A struct {
    aSlice aSlice
}
```

Which makes sense why its values are only accessible via `A.aSlice` indexing.

Answer (score 1):

If you declare the slice as a exported type, then you can access the embedded slice. But you still can't do indexing.

```
package a
type Slice []string
type A struct {
   Slice
}

package main
import "a"
func main() {
  _a := a.AB{[]string{"hello", "world"}}
  fmt.Println(_a.Slice[0])
}
```