# Go: Embedding a primitive type?

Tags: go, struct, embedding

Suppose we have this piece of code:

```
type User struct {
    int32
    Name string
}
```

Can this type of embedding be useful?
Does `int32` have any methods which other can call on instances of `User`?
How can I access the value of the `int32` that `User` is embedding?

Comment: You can use User as that type.  `if user > 0 ...` as an example.  If the primitive had methods, those would be promoted as well.

Comment: @eduncan911 can you paste a sample code? I was not able to do this on the Go Playground.

Comment: @eduncan911 No, you can't do that: `u > int32(0)` results in `invalid operation: u > int32(0) (mismatched types User and int32)`

Comment: Ah, that's right. U still need to access the property by name: https://play.golang.org/p/mIk_7ewRkN

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The type `int32` is a [predeclared type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Predeclared_identifiers), it has no methods. To verify:

```
fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(int32(0)).NumMethod()) // Prints 0
```

You can refer to all embedded fields by using the unqualified type name as the field name ([Spec: Struct types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types)), predeclared types are no exception. See this example:

```
u := User{3, "Bob"}
fmt.Printf("%#v\n", u)
u.int32 = 4
fmt.Println(u.int32)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/SVNgV3FE81)):

```
main.User{int32:3, Name:"Bob"}
4
```

Primary gain of using embedding is:

- methods of the embedded type get promoted, so it's easier to implement interfaces (you don't need to provide methods that get promoted)
- you can "override" methods of the embedded type (on the embedder type): provide your own implementation which will be called when a value of your embedder type is used
- and fields of the embedded type get promoted, so code is shorter to refer to promoted fields (field name is left out).

By embedding predeclared types such as `int32`, you don't get any advantage over using just a regular field (*named*, not embedded field), as the `int32` type doesn't have any methods or fields.

Going forward, besides not having any advantage, you even have a disadvantage. Since predeclared type names start with lowercased letters, embedding them implicitly makes them *unexported*, so you can only refer to them in the declaring package of the embedder type. If you make them regular, *named* fields, you may choose to use an uppercased name to make it exported, or a lowercased name to make it unexported.

Comment: Interesting use of the '<kbd>' tags

Comment: Interestingly, primitive types that contains spaces or symbols (arrays / slices, maps, channels) cannot be embedded in this way, a "typedef" (type declaration) is needed, like `type MapStringInt map[string]int` or `type RecvChanInt <-chan int`.

Comment: @SiuChingPong-AsukaKenji- That's actually the consequence of that the unqualified type name "becomes" the field name, and characters such as `[ ] < -` are not allowed in [identifiers](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Identifiers).

Comment: Yup, I noticed that. But sadly, only the "methods" of the anonymous fields are promoted, not the "operators". So, even if an anonymous `RecvChanInt` (a.k.a. `<-chan int`) is embedded in `User` above, one still cannot do `<- u`, but only `<- u.RecvChanInt`.

Comment: @SiuChingPong-AsukaKenji- And that is because it would be _ambiguous_. Imagine you embed 2 channels (2 different types with channels as underlying types), and you write `<- u`. Which channel would that mean?

Comment: The same problem (ambiguity) also exists in the current embedding, so allowing that does NOT make it worse: https://play.golang.org/p/tBaNUbCXbF

Comment: @SiuChingPong-AsukaKenji- True. I revise my comment: it's not allowed because the operand of the receive operator must be of channel type, and a struct is clearly not one of those.

Comment: Yes, of course, in the current Go language. As I said, [[But sadly, only the "methods" of the anonymous fields are promoted, not the "operators".]]. It would be nice if this is allowed, since one of the most wanted features is doing a `range` on a custom type.

Comment: @FrankerZ This use has been long ago declared to be very incorrect: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181774/stricter-kbd-usage-rules

Comment: @DenysSéguret I didn't know about that. Thanks for letting me know.